# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'replace' - Replace whitespaces with underscore

Tags: python, csv

I want to replace whitespace with underscore in a string. So that for example:

"AmericInn_Hotel & Suites Sibley becomes "AmericInn_Hotel_&_Suites_Sibley"

so here is what i attempted to do

```
with open('Hallos.csv','r') as csvinput:
with open('Hallos2.csv', 'w') as csvoutput:
    writer = csv.writer(csvoutput, lineterminator='\n')
    reader = csv.reader(csvinput, delimiter=';') #or delimiter ";"


    all = []
    row = next(reader)
    row.append('Param 2')
    row.append("Param 1")
    all.append(row)


    for row in reader:
        row.append("AA")
        row.append("AmericInn_" + row[0][9:])
        if row[0]:
            all.append(row.replace(" ", "_"))
```

here is what it gives me:

```
  all.append(row.replace(" ", "_"))
  AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

It would help if somebody told me a different way around. Any feedback is appreciated.

Comment: `all.append([i.replace(" ", "_") for i in row])`

Comment: As the error message is telling you, *you don't have a string*. `row` is a `list` (which is why you can e.g. `append`) - if you want to apply `replace` to each string within it, you will have to iterate over them explicitly.

Comment: You put a different error message in the title and in the question. Which is it?